# How can I add a cart image in my navigation bar?

Tags: image, cart, navigationbar, insertafter, weebly

I am trying to add an image of a cart after my "Cart" button in navigation bar.

Can anyone help me in doing so? I am using Weebly to create my website.

Here is my website: http://poloniafoods.weebly.com/

Thanks in advance, 
Justin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a static nav bar with image buttons for "Home, Account, Checkout, etc." Then follow the below steps..

1. Create the individual button images. These should all be the same height. Each one is a separate image and is labeled "Home" for example.
2. Upload each of your buttons to your template's "images" folder. For example: "includes/templates/classic/images/"
3. Open the "tpl_header.php" file for the template you're using. For example: "includes/templates/template_default/common/tpl_header.php"
4. Find the line of code that reads
   PHP Code: `<?php } // no HEADER_SALES_TEXT or SHOW_BANNERS_GROUP_SET2 ?>`
5. On the next line, insert this code:

PHP Code:

```
<!-- begin navTabs navigation -->
```

6. Repeat the  portion of code for each button link. You of course have to customize the link destination and the image location for each. The Width and Height should also match the dimensions of that particular image.

After this, you can use your stylesheet.css and other template files to align everything, and it should work!

Comment: I thought there was a much easier way to do this through css with the :after {} isn't there? Also, I just want one image of a cart after my cart button.

Comment: is there any way of doing it through css only?

Comment: Thanks @justinpees... what u actually want will u pls. Tell me so, will help u better...